# Pattern Matching to find trailing spaces outside of text fields in a line

Tags: java, regex

I have to validate the lines from a text file. The line would be something like below.

`"Field1" "Field2" "Field3 Field_3.1 Field3.2" 23 3445 "Field5".`

The delimiter here is a single Space(\s). If more than one space present outside of text fields, then the line should be rejected. For example,

**Note :** \s would be present as literal space and not as \s in the line. For easy reading I mentioned space as \s

**Invalid:**
`"Field1"\\s\\s"Field2" "Field3 Field_3.1 Field3.2" 23\\s\\s3445 "Field5".` //two or more spaces between "Field1" and "Field2" or numeric fields 23  3445. \s would be present as literal space and not as \s

**Valid**
`"Field1\\s\\s" "\\s\\sField2" "Field3\\s\\sField_3.1\\s\\sField3.2" 23 3445 "Field5".` //two or more spaces within third field "Field3  Field_3.1  Field3.2" or at the end/beginning of any field as in first two fields.

I created a Pattern as below to validate the Spaces in between. But it's not working as expected when there're more than two Strings and a numeric  present inside a Field wrapped by Double quotes like `"Field3  Field_3.1  123"`

```
public class SpaceValidation
{
   public static void main(String ar[])
   {
       String spacePattern_1 = "[\"^\\n]\\s{2,}?(\".*\")|\\s\\s\\d|\\d\\s\\s";
String line1 = "Field3  Field_3.1  "; // valid and pattern doesn't find it as invalid - Works as expected
String line2 = "Field3  Field_3.1  123";//Valid and but pattern find it as invalid - Not working as expected.
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(spacePattern_1);
      Matcher matLine1 = pattern.matcher(line1);
      Matcher matLine2 = pattern.matcher(line2);
      if(matLine1.find())
      {
        sysout("Invalid Line1");
      }

      if(matLine2.find())
      {
        sysout("Invalid Line2");
      }
}
```

I have tried another pattern given below. But due to backtracking issues reported I have to avoid the below pattern, Even this one is not working when there are more than two subfields present two or more spaces in a line.

```
(\".*\")\\s{2,}?(\".*\")|\\s\\s\\d|\\d\\s\\s

 // * or . shouldn't be present more than once in the same condition to prevent backtracking, hence I have to use negation of \\n in the above code
```

Kindly let me know how I could resolve this using pattern for fields such as `"field3  field3.1  123"`, which is a valid field. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
After little bit tinkering, I narrowed down the issue to digit. The lines becomes invalid only if the third subfield is numeric (`"Field 3  Field3.1  123"`). For alphabets its working fine.

Here in the pattern `\\s\\s\\d` seems to be the culprit. It's that condition that flags the third subfield as invalid(numeric subfield 123). But I need that to validate numeric fields present outside of the DoubleQuotes.

Comment: What about `\"[^\\s]\"` instead of `\".*\"`?

Comment: one more Space can present inside the text field

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew, I'm adding the PatternMatching tag as I'm looking for certain patterns in the Line of String using Java Pattern class.

Comment: My fault. I meant `\"[^\"]\"`.

Comment: Regex is what you are looking for, not pattern matching. See tag description where it is written that you should not use it if regex is what you mean.

Comment: dan1st but that doesn't solve the digit problem I have mentioned. If the third subfield is digit still it is flagging as invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\d+)(?:\s(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\d+))*$
```

If you are using it to extract lines from a multiline document:

```
(?m)^(?:\"[^\"\n\r]*\"|\d+)(?:\h(?:\"[^\"\n\r]*\"|\d+))*\r?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8CtMBZ/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a string (line, if you use `(?m)` or `Pattern.MULTILINE`)
- `(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\d+)` - either `"` + zero or more chars other than `"` + `"`, or one or more digits
- `(?:\s(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\d+))*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\s` - a single whitespace
  - `(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\d+)` - either `"` + zero or more chars other than `"` + `"`, or one or more digits
- `$` - end of string

The second pattern contains `\h` instead of `\s` to only match horizontal whitespaces, `[^\"\n\r]` matches any char other than `"`, line feed and carriage return.

In Java:

```java
String pattern = "^(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\\d+)(?:\\s(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\\d+))*$";
String pattern = "(?m)^(?:\"[^\"\n\r]*\"|\\d+)(?:\\h(?:\"[^\"\n\r]*\"|\\d+))*\r?$";
```

Comment: Wiktor, the line that I use is of variable length it and it may have variable number of fields. But what I have to validate is "No more than one space should be present outside of the text field or adjacent to the numeric fields". How do I find that line has two or more spaces outside of the text field?

Comment: @Rajesh2389 The one that does not match `String pattern = "^(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\\d+)(?:\\s(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\\d+))*$"`

Comment: This is working for me. But if I change this block [^\"] to something like Single Quote [^\'] it's not working or [^\n] for that matter. I do not want to ignore the double quotes as they will be present too inside, but single quote or \n can be ignored.  I still can replace those double quotes and check against that pattern. But wondering why it's behaving like that if it's replaced by some other character.

Comment: @Rajesh2389 No idea what is not working when you change all `"` with `'`. Your question has nothing to do with single quotes.

Comment: "Field""S" -> This will be considered as single field. My bad, I missed it in the question.
Even if it's not possible, could you please add that comment to the answer, I'll mark it as the answer? You saved my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rajesh2389 You will need `String pattern = "^(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+)(?:\\s(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+))*$"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250813/discussion-between-rajesh2389-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Apologies to bother you repeatedly. One more question on top of that regex, which I just noticed while testing it. Out of two numeric fields, the second one could have dot as decimal separator, i.e., 100.0 though it's optional. How do we handle such scenario.
I tried "^(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+\\.\\d)(?:\\s(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"‌​[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+\\.\\d))*$"
But its not recognizing it tried it with [.] as well

Comment: The following did the trick. Please correct if there's something wrong. However, it's working for me.
"^(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+|\\d+[.]\\d+)(?:\\s(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"‌​[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+|\\d+[.]\\d+))*$"

Comment: @Rajesh2389 Matching int or floats: `String pattern = "^(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?:\\s(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?))*$"`

Comment: ,Thanks Wiktor. is it possible to break this into 4 parts ? I can break regex into 2 parts. Due to it's length, I'm getting some code reliability issues. I mean it may throw StackOverflow exception for larger inputs.

Comment: @Rajesh2389 This regex is reliable and fast enough, it won't throw any stack overflow exceptions, unless you modified it somehow.

Comment: That's Sonar Gating issue. . Though It works fast enough for me.

Comment: @Rajesh2389 Sonar regex "analysis"/"evaluation" is shit. That is all I can say about it. 99% questions about "Sonar + regex" are all false positives here on SO.

Comment: Agree. But my build wouldn't go unless this "Regular expressions should not overflow the stack" issue is solved. I'm trying to compress , modify as per their suggestions. But none seems to working. Let me see. Kindly let me if there are any alternatives . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rajesh2389 You must disable that warning. Sonar developers who do not understand anything about what catastrophic backtracking prone patterns look like must be fired. There is a less efficient equivalent of the regex, `String pattern = "^(?:\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?:\\s(?:\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?))*$"`, but I believe Sonar won't be able to parse it correctly either.

Comment: Wish I could disable that along with the several other stupid coverage related rules(Not all) as well. As you said, sonar didn't flag anything with this pattern. That's amazing. I really appreciate your time and effort for solving this!! Thank You very much Wiktor!!